# Haskell apply single value to a list of functions

Tags: haskell

For an assignment I am working on a list of functions `[Int -> Int]` (eg. `[(+3), (*4), (+1)]` ) and I would like to apply a single `Int` to each of them, in turn creating a list of results `[Int]`

I already searched a lot, but I am unable to find a way to do such an operation. Using `map` does not work as I would expect. The related error is this:

```
ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Num ((Label -> Label) -> a)
```

As requested the code:

```
data Tree = Node (Label -> Label) Label [Tree]
type Label = Int

testTree = Node (+1) 3 [ Node (+1) 5 [], Node (+1) 4 [Node (+1) 1 [], Node (+2) 7 []]]

listify :: Tree -> [(Label -> Label)]
listify t = [(getNodeFunction t)] ++ concat(map (listify) (getSubTrees t))


*Main> map (\f -> f 7) (listify testTree)
```

this actually works. Had a piece of faulty code in the file still, sorry for the fuss.

Comment: show us the code that uses map

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but your `Tree` type is just a bit weird. I don't know what you're trying to do with it exactly, but it seems to fuse together two concepts: making a tree of things, and pairing certain things together. You might want to consider using `Data.Tree` (from the `containers` package that comes with GHC), at which point something pretty close to your type can be expressed as `Tree (Label -> Label, Label)`. By breaking it up like this, you would get to use all sorts of general-purpose `Tree` functions.

Comment: This tree type is given in the assignment. Presumably with the intent of annoying the ever living hell out of the students.

Comment: Random style comment: `[(blah)] ++ ..` can be written as `blah : ...`. Also, using pattern matching instead of getters would look better in this case: `listify (Node f l subt) = ...`. Finally, no need to parenthesise `(listify)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying a list of functions in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400825/applying-a-list-of-functions-in-haskell)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the `$` operator, which stands for function application.

```
> map ($ 3) [(+3), (*4), (+1)]
[6,12,4]
```

This basically expands to `[(+3) $ 3, (*4) $ 3, (+1) $ 3]`, which is just function application.

Answer (score 10):

Basically this is an applicative job. You may do like

```
λ> [(+3), (*4), (+1)] <*> pure 3 -- or [3]
[6,12,4]
```

Comment: This requires some explanation, since `<*>` is not a descriptive identifier, and nobody wants to go hunting for a billion layers of implicit meanings and type relationships of such write-only code. Also, using `pure` instead of just `[…]` further obfuscates the types behind the scenes. (It’s never good when there is a behind the scenes that is not obvious from looking at the code itself.)

Comment: @Evi1M4chine Sadly the [Applicative class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors#:~:text=Advanced%20Haskell&text=Like%20monads%2C%20applicative%20functors%20are,with%20a%20wealth%20of%20applications.) which is inbetween the Functor and Monad, perhaps a little bit neglected. However as per this particular job, it seems to be the most suitable one. `pure` on the other hand is just the equivalent of `return` of Monads in the Applicative context nothing more nothing less. If you are coding in Haskell you should know that `<*>` operator is as common as `<$>` and `>>=`.

Answer (score 4):

You also can use [list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) for this. This line is enough for your example:

`[ f 3 | f <- [(+3), (*4), (+1)] ]`

This applies every function in the list on the right hand side to the value (`3` in this case) on the left hand side.

---

For a more general version, this could be helpful:

```
applyFuns :: [(a->b)] -> a -> [b]
applyFuns fs x = [ f x | f <- fs ]

applyFuns [(+3), (*4), (+1)] 3
```

The Function `applyFuns` takes a list of functions from Type `a->b` as the first and a value of type `b` as the second. The result is a list of type `b` that contains the result of every function in the first list applied to the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

If `flist` is the list of functions and `x` is the argument, you need `map (\f -> f x) flist`.

For example

```
Prelude> map (\f -> f 10) [(4 +), (3 *)]
[14,30]
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old, but I feel like there oughta be an answer mentioning `sequence`:

```
> sequence [(+3), (*4), (+1)] 3
[6,12,4]
```

(These days, `sequenceA` is considered the modern replacement for `sequence`; it has the same behavior whenever both typecheck, but typechecks in slightly more situations. No difference here, though, so I like the slightly less-noisy name for this.)

Comment: Yes, a nice answer to keep in mind, but I think any use of the `(->) r` monad comes with a moral obligation to point out the use of the `(->) r` monad.

Comment: What is the (->) r monad? @K.A.Buhr

Comment: For any type `r`, the type `(->) r` has a monad instance.  It functions similarly to `Reader r`, but without the explicit syntax of `ask`, etc., so it can be quite confusing when it's used without explanation.  It's hard to provide a more complete answer in a comment, so maybe ask a separate Stack Overflow question if you want more details.